# Selecting test data for recurrent neural network (RNN)

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

Am I right in thinking that when it comes to selecting the test data for use with a recurrent neural network, that you can only either take a portion at the start or end of the complete data set, because if I take a sub-sample then it will break the sequence of the train set?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with neural networks, Yes, you must take the start or the end portion. Train sets could be explained better by Micheal Nielson, on the Dahl papers... maybe check there.

Comment: With a feed-forward network it would be possible to pick data at random from the complete data set and remove it for use as a test set.  But with RNN it's sequence-based, so I assume if I start chopping bits of sequence out of the data set then it's not ideal because then there'll be pieces of sequence missing from the training set. I just want to check my thought there is correct. So this question is specifically about RNNs.